# Microsoft Exchange migration with powershell

Tags: powershell, migration, exchange-server

We are working on Microsoft Exchange migration with power shell. we successfully executed the "perpare-moverequest.ps1" command. then we are trying to run  "New-MoveRequest" command . but we are getting error. because it asking for SID history and password migration permission issue. there are many tools which can help us for Password migration like ADMT tool to allow password migration. but we are trying to achieve it from power shell command. there is command available which is "import-module SIDhistory" but its throwing error

- Import-Module sidhistory
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\Users....sidhistory.psd1:String) [Import- 
    Module], MissingMemberException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidManifest,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Either we are missing some command or there would be any other command to achieve this. please guide us .

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run Import-Module ActiveDirectory, and after you've successfully imported it, then run   Import-Module SIDHistory.
P.S. in some cases (depending which powershell version you are using) you will need to import the module by providing the full path. E.g.

Import-Module Name 'C:\SomePath\modules\SIDHistory\SIDHistory.psm1'

Cheers.